# C# Mutex not beeing released? EZCAD2MUTEX_MARKING | Check if EzCad is Marking

Tags: c#, locking, mutex

I'm trying to detect whether the EzCad2 software is currently laser marking (mutex locked/signaled) or idle (mutex released/nonsignaled) using a publicly documented mutex. According to the documentation, such an approach is desired and possible.

Here is an excerpt:

*"Option Enable Mark Mutex (EZCAD2MUTEX_MARKING):
This option is used to synchronize the Ezcad program with third-party programs. If checked, the Ezcad software creates a mutex object named “EZCAD2MUTEX_MARKING”. The mark command cannot be executed until the mutex is 'signaled' by other programs. After marking, the mutex will be switched to 'nonsignaled' state by Ezcad software."*

I want to achieve this with the following code:

```
    private void Foo()
    {
        Mutex tmpMutex = null;

        try
        {
            string mutexname = "EZCAD2MUTEX_MARKING";
    
            if(!Mutex.TryOpenExisting(mutexname, out tmpMutex))
            {
                tmpMutex = new Mutex(true, mutexname, out bool createdNew);
            }
    
            while(true)
            {
                if(tmpMutex.WaitOne(1)) // Ezcad not marking
                {
                    Console.Write("mutex free"); 
    
                    tmpMutex.ReleaseMutex(); // EzCad could mark after release
    
                    Console.WriteLine(" + released successfully"); 
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("mutex blocked"); // EzCad is Marking
                }
    
                Thread.Sleep(50); // Wait for a Bit before next round
            }
    
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(tmpMutex != null)
            {
                tmpMutex.Wait();
                tmpMutex.ReleaseMutex();
                tmpMutex.Close();
                tmpMutex.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

For unexplained and non-reproducible reasons, EzCad stops responding after several iterations. My program remains in the "mutex free" branch. Either the mutex is not being released by `tmpMutex.ReleaseMutex()` or EzCad is not taking the mutex anymore.

Now the Catch at which point i think there's a logic error in my code:
EzCad stays in that state forever if my Software is still running. Once i kill my software, EzCad starts to continue as normal.

Does my program have any obvious logic errors?

I tried following things:

- Closing + Disposing the Mutex after Releasing it
- Using tmpMutex.WaitOne(0) > should be non blocking and not claiming the mutex
- Using tmpMutex.WaitOne(1) > should claim the mutex if free (if becoming free until timeout expired)
- different timings + delays within loops

**EDIT**

- Simulating EzCad with my own (Claim & Release Functions):

With that, I've seen the same behavior as EzCad, which is that my main programm isn't responding (Unable to execute WaitOne(0) successfully - and so isn't able to reclaim the mutex) even though I executed ReleaseMutex on my simulation helper.

If I Kill the helper my main software returns back to normal just like EzCad does.
So I im pretty shure something about the execution or use of "ReleaseMutex" Method is wrong even though it's executed without throwing a exception.

Comment: Does the documentation tells you something about if the mentioned mutex is global or lokal?

Comment: @Ralf the information in the excerpt given above is the only information i have on it. It's a named Mutex accessable from outside its process - so global I think?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ORIGINAL APROACH ABANDONED**

I now abandoned the Mutex aproach, since I found another, easier method of checking for EzCad's cctivity.

I'm sure the Code of @RalfBas Visscher should work.

I did finally realize that Mutex really isn't meant to be used like this. Its real use is to provide threadsave access to resources, not to check for other programs activity.

For those who may be interested in the new approach:
I used a empty text-Object in Database with output set to a .txt file. Once this file exists, I know EzCad started marking. And delete it after a given time (const int timeMs for each individual object)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be in the `Thread.Sleep(50);`

If you do this, the complete thread will sleep. Not just the executing context! Chances are that EzCAD is running on the same thread. So it won't get any executing time during your sleep. In that case, your application has the mutex 'always' claimed.

Try Task.Sleep(). You may want to use async and await.

---

I've changed your code somewhat.

1. **Single MutexWrapper Class**: Consolidating mutex-related logic into a single class (`MutexWrapper`) is a good practice. It encapsulates the details of mutex management and makes it easier to handle any future changes or updates related to mutex handling in one place.
2. **ScopedLock Class**: The `ScopedLock` class helps ensure that the mutex is always properly disposed, even in the presence of exceptions.
3. **Asynchronous Code**: Making the code asynchronous with `await Task.Delay()` is a good choice if you need to introduce delays without blocking the thread. This is especially useful in UI applications or scenarios where you want to keep the application responsive while waiting.

```
public class MutexWrapper : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Mutex mutex;
    private readonly string mutexname;

    public MutexWrapper(string mutexname)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(mutexname))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mutexname));

        this.mutexname = mutexname;
        Mutex? tmpMutex;
        Mutex.TryOpenExisting(mutexname, out tmpMutex);
        if (tmpMutex != null)
            mutex = tmpMutex;
        else
            mutex = new Mutex(true, mutexname, out bool createdNew);
    }
    
    public bool WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        return mutex.WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout);
    }

    public void ReleaseMutex()
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        mutex.Close();
        mutex.Dispose();
    }
}


public class ScopedLock : IDisposable
{
    private readonly MutexWrapper mutex;
    public ScopedLock(MutexWrapper mutex) { 
        this.mutex = mutex;
        mutex.WaitOne(0);  //Wait forever
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}


private async void Foo()
{
    string mutexname = "EZCAD2MUTEX_MARKING";

    using (MutexWrapper mutexWrapper = new MutexWrapper(mutexname))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            using (ScopedLock scopedLock = new ScopedLock(mutexWrapper))
            {
                Console.Write("Protected code");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("No more protected code");
            await Task.Delay(50); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I now tried with Task.Delay and also completely without Delays. Still doens't work. I dont get why even when I run waitOne() and ReleaseMutex syncronously via UI, it doensnt seem to release the mutex. Isn't there a simpler way to just watch if the mutex is signaled or not?

Comment: I have changed my answer somewhat, could you try this code? Also, if it still doesn't work. Can you try to not take the mutex at all? If the problem still occurs, then something different goes wrong

Comment: Hi, I found another Solution to my Program without working with the Mutex. It's also clear that using a Mutex this way isn't a stable and recommended Solution. Unfortunally I can't test your Code since i removed all of my code arround it. Anyways - thank's for your effort :/
Should i remove the Post or Flag it as done?

Comment: I don't know what stack overflow regulations are. I guess, mark it as done. You might want to take the time to explain how you solved your problem if others have the same problem.